# bootstrap-table export event?

Tags: jquery, export, bootstrap-table

I am using [table-bootstrap](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) and i would like to post process some of the data  before exporting the event occur. The post processing is going to be sending the selected data for export to the back-end and save it to database. In cases everything sucessed, the client side process the export.

I am already using the export extensions for exporting the data. can 
anyone advise on how to implement on export, and before export events?

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but now in bootstrap table documentation

https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/#events

They have provided an Event called

> onExportSave

and a method called

> exportTable

[Screenshot of URL Incase Documentation Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgWXS.png)